# Convert fraction to an infinite series with alternating sign

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
f(m)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\Bigl(\frac{-1}{m}\Bigr)^n}\\
$$
converges at $\frac{m}{m+1}$ where $1 < m < \infty$. In other words, where $m$ approaches $1$ it converges at $0.5$ and where m approaches $\infty$ it converges at $1$.

Does that mean that I can multiply any real number $m$ with $2(f(m)-0.5)$ to converge at that number? It makes sense algebraically, although I might as well just multiply $m$ by $1$, but with an infinite series, $m$ should surely be factored into every term?

Is there maybe another way to convert a fraction into a variation of a geometric series?

Comment: Huh? Your series doesn't converge at all. The terms don't approach zero.

Comment: See:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum(-1%2Fm)%5En 
and
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum(-1%2F3)%5En

Comment: sorry, I've added brackets now

Comment: OK, now you have a geometric series with first term $-1/m$ and common ratio $-1/m$, so its sum is $-1/(m+1)$, not $m/(m+1)$. Perhaps you want to start with $n=0$ instead of $n=1$?

Comment: Cool, thanks. I've fixed n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following series will converge at m:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{1.5m}{-2^n}}$$